# Python sockets not working between two PC

Tags: python, sockets, networking, runtime-error

I am trying to communicate via sockets between two PCs but it doesnt work. I am able to communicate within the same PC but not when I try to do it between two PCs in the same network.

I have tried IP 0.0.0.0, IP from the computer and getlocalhost, nothing has worked.

I have gotten errors saying the server actively refuses it or timeout errors. I have made sure the ports that are being used are open and firewall is not intefering and that the server is actively listening.

Server:

```
class server(object):
    def server_socket(self):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        port = 3125
        s.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
        s.listen(3)
        print ('socket is listening')

        while True:
            c, addr = s.accept()
            message = pickle.loads(c.recv(1024))
            FullScreenApp.set_dic(self, message)
```

Client

```
class client(object):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        print("3")

    def client_socket(self,z):
        s = socket.socket()
        port = 3125
        s.connect(('localhost', port))
        s.sendall(pickle.dumps(z))
        s.close()
```

Comment: localhost is a loopback i.e. it cannot connect 2 PCs. You need to connect to the router assigned IP of the server computer.

Comment: I have tried doing '0.0.0.0' IP on server/ 'IP of server computer' on client and also 'IP of server computer' on server and 'IP of server computer' on client, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is also a loopback address. If you check the network settings on your computer you should be able to find the router-assigned IP.

Comment: I tried that but I get the following: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond". I have seen firewall is a common issue when trying to connect with sockets on different PCs, but I did disable them and still get that.